# What are the errors in this code?

Tags: python, error-handling

Assume you have written a new function that checks to see if your game character has any life left. If the character does not have any life left, the function should print 'dead', if it has less than or equal to 5 life points left the function should print 'almost dead', otherwise it should print 'alive'.

```
am_i_alive(): 
    hit_points = 20
    if hit_points = 0: 
        print 'dead'
    else hit_points <= 5: 
        print 'almost dead'
    else: 
        print 'alive'

am_i_alive()
```

Comment: Where's your unit test case?  If you would write some test cases, you'd know what the errors were, wouldn't you?

Comment: @S.Lott In the case of the code displayed, I'd say it's its own unit test ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def am_i_alive(): 
    hit_points = 20
    if hit_points == 0: 
        print 'dead'
    elif hit_points <= 5: 
        print 'almost dead'
    else: 
        print 'alive'

am_i_alive()
```

1. You need the `def` keyword to define a function.
2. You need to use `==` and not `=` for comparisons.
3. You chain if statements using `elif`.

other than that, it looks good. As in correct and will compile. It will always yield the same value though.

A better way to do it is:

```
def am_i_alive(hit_points): 
    if hit_points == 0:
        print 'dead'
    elif hit_points <= 5: 
        print 'almost dead'
    else: 
        print 'alive'

am_i_alive(20)
am_i_alive(3)
am_i_alive(0)
```

Here, we are passing an 'argument' to the function. we call it with `am_i_alive(x)` where `x` can be any number. In the code for the function `am_i_alive`, whatever we put in place of `x` becomes the value referred to by `hit_points`.

A function can take two arguments as well. (in fact, up to 255 arguments)

```
def am_i_alive(hit_points, threshold): 
    if hit_points == 0:
        print 'dead'
    elif hit_points <= threshold: 
        print 'almost dead'
    else: 
        print 'alive'

am_i_alive(20, 5)
am_i_alive(3, 2)
am_i_alive(0, 10)
```

Can you understand what the last version does?

I didn't read it because python is not my first language, but I'm told that this is a very good [introduction to python and programming](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/html/).

Comment: You also need `elif` instead of `else if`.

Comment: @Fred Larson. Good looking out. I'm taking a break from some C coding ;)

Comment: @Jostlyn Walton, be sure that you take note of Fred Larson's comment.